# Scaling an Object Using a Single Face or Edge

Tags: transforms

Imagine I have a simple bowl. What is the best way to scale the entire object so that the base has an accurate diameter of 50mm? In effect I need to scale the object by the dimensions of the bottom face. How can it be done?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Objects with circular symmetry almost beg for the *Screw modifier*
Using only a profile, you can precisely adjust the diameter of any part.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Someone will probably give an elegant method, here are some trashy ones (if I've correctly understood your question):

You could separate (as new object) an edge (that is aligned with X or Y) from the bottom of the bowl, open the *N panel > Item > Transform*, select the bowl object, shift select the edge, scale up the edge until you reach the wanted dimension, press <kbd>Shift</kbd> while scaling if you want more precision:

[image]

Or parent the bowl to the edge, scale the edge, or type the good *Scale* values so that it reaches the good *Dimension* value. Don't forget to apply the scale afterwards.

You could use a measure tool: Duplicate 2 vertices of the bottom of your bowl and fill an edge between them, activate *Edge Length* in the *Viewport Overlays* panel, scale up your whole mesh until you reach the wanted length:

[image]

You can also activate the *MeasureIt* addon, select the edge, open the *N panel > View > MeasureIt Tools*, click on *Show*, click on *Segment*, and its length will display (you can remove the length display if you click on the *X* or *Delete all* a bit further down). Scale up your bowl until you get the wanted length:

[image]