# Blender 3: Resize to exact dimensions without affecting scale

Tags: transforms

I'm struggling to figure out how to resize an object (a cube, a plane) to an exact size wthout its scale also changing.

**tl;dr**: I want to add a cube, and set its dimensions to exactly 400x300x40 cm while keeping the scale at exactly 0.01

**Requirements**: Unreal Engine :)

Unreal Engine's units are centimeters, and Blender's are meters. A common solution to this seems to be: set scale in Blender to 0.01, and then resize the objects as needed:

[image]

However, if I want to create an object with exact dimensions on the same scale from scratch, I struggle.

**Problem**

Let's say I want to create a wall, 4x3x0.4 meters (400x300x40 cm).

- The default cube will have a scale of 1.0, which is expected.
- When I set the scale to 0.01, it becomes very small, which is also expected.

Now:

If I change cube dimensions in `Object Mode, its scale changes (this is also expected, I think)

Right after setting the scale

[image]

Right after setting dimensions

[image]

If I switch to Edit Mode, and use `Scale...

- there's no way to see object dimensions except to switch back to Object Mode?
- there's no way to set exact dimensions? Numeric input resizes by that number, doesn't set the size to this number

So the question is: How do I set an object's scale exactly without changing the scale?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried using exact dimensions in Blender with scale at 1.0 and then adjusting the scale on export? There are also plenty of tools for measuring in edit mode with the ruler and MeasureIt add-on.

Comment: maybe use one of the methods I cite here? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/262065/scaling-an-object-using-a-single-face-or-edge/262070#262070

Comment: @RobertGützkow Ah, thank you for MeasureIt, I wouldn't have discovered it myself. I have't tried changing scale on export yet (partly because I already have some reference models in 0.01, and didn't think of changing their scale)

Comment: @moonboots Thanks! I found the steps a bit too advanced for me so far, but MeasurIt will serve me so far. Thank you!

Comment: @Mamut you can always apply the scale with CTRL + A > Scale to get it back to 1.0.

Comment: @RobertGützkow The thing is, I want the scale to stay at 0.01 for later export to Unreal Engine :)

Comment: @Mamut Yes, but you can keep all objects at scale 1.0 within Blender and then just adjust  the scale once in the exporters settings. Applying the scale for your reference models would help to ensure a consistent scale rather than having to adjust each one individually.

Comment: @RobertGützkow ah! Thank you, I'll try that!